# Jquery get selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, selector

I have this jquery script :

```
$.fn.myFoo = function(){
    alert(this.selector)
    alert($(this).selector);
}
```

then i call it like so.

```
$('#myID').myFoo();
```

I need but it returns empty: i need it to return "myID" i can't seem to find a way to do this can some one help please?

Comment: What happens if you simply alert(this); ?

Comment: The code you supplied works for me, in Firefox using jQuery 1.3.1. Actually, it alerts the selector twice. What browser/jQuery version are you using?

Comment: i hadn't realise that it was like so: ----- $.fn.myFoo = function(){
    foo = function(){alert(this.selector)
    alert($(this).selector);
}
}

------ therefore the this function was getting foo i think instead of myFoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to get the id then you can use

```
$(this).attr ( "id" );
```

inside the function.

See [**attr**](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr)

Comment: thank you the $(this).selector works aswell but i had putten it within another function and did not include this. Thank you both